# Shell scripting - which word is first alphabetically?

Tags: bash, shell, alphabetical

How can you check which words is first alphabetically between two words?
For example in the code

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="apple"
var2="bye"

if [ $var1 \> $var2 ]
then
echo $var1
else
echo $var2
fi
```

I want it to print apple, since apple comes before bye alphabetically, but it isnt working as intended. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need to do to solve the immediate problem is reverse the sense of your statement, since the "less than" operator is `<` rather than `>`.

Doing so will get it working correctly:

```
if [ $var1 \< $var2 ]
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the `[[` variant which *doesn't* require the escaping:

```
if [[ $var1 < $var2 ]]
```

I prefer the latter because:

1. it looks nicer; and
2. the `[[` variant is much more expressive and powerful.

Comment: Is there also a less-than-or-equal-to operator? [[ $var1 <= $var2 ]] doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Jaan, no, bash has no string-based compound operators such as `<=`. You can emulate it quite easily by just negating the opposite operation: the conceptual `[[ $a <= $b ]]` can be written as the actual `[[ ! $a > $b ]]`.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use the `[[ ]]` construct and print out the one that is **less than** the other

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="apple"
var2="bye"

if [[ $var1 < $var2 ]]; then
  echo $var1
else
  echo $var2
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! I normally program in C++ so I'm used to thinking that a word that comes first alphabetically is greater than one that comes after.

Comment: @user1161080: Care to elaborate where in C++ that assertion holds? :-)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are suffering from two misconceptions about (bash) shell scripting.

First the line `if [ $var1 > $var2 ] then echo ...` is syntactically wrong and you should really paste your example commands or code rather than trying to re-type them from memory.  It would be fine if you'd said `if [[ "$var1" > "$var2" ]]; then ...` or `if [ "$var" \> "$var2" ]; then ...`.

Note that `[[` is a bash specific conditional expression while [ (single bracket) introduces the shell built-in implementation of the `/usr/bin/[` (alias for `/usr/bin/test`) command.

The old `[` (`test`) command has much more constrained features than the `[[` support in bash.  It only support `-lt`, `-eq` ... and other *integer* comparisons and the various file and value length (`-z' and`-n`) and other tests.  It has no support for lexical/string or pattern (regex nor glob) comparisons. The`bash`built-in for`[`supports a number of the`[[` extensions but, as shown some of them have to be explicitly escaped from the legacy parsing.

Also note that it's dangerous to use bar dereferences of `$var` (vs `"$var"` with the quotes).  If the value assigned to `var` has any embedded spaces or various other operators which might be conflated with the switches to the `test` command.

Also you need the `;` to separate the `if` command from the `then` clause.

Trying to write shell scripts as though shell were a normal programming language will lead you to quite a bit of this sort of confusion.  Shells, such as `bash` have relatively little syntax and built-in functionality and most of that is glue around running commands.  In early versions of UNIX the shell didn't have any built-in tests and relied entirely on the external `test` command.  Over time more and more functionality was built-in the shell, often through aliases to those old commands (`/usr/bin/[' is literally a link to the`/usr/bin/test`command and the shell built-ins for`[`and`test` are internal aliases to one another and implemented as (mostly?) compatible with the older (and still extant) external binaries.

Similarly all arithmetic operations in the early Bourne shells were done using external commands such as `/usr/bin/expr`.  Korn shell and Bash added $((...)) and `let` and `((...))` expressions
for evaluating arithmetic expressions from within the shell without external command support.

Other examples relate to the support for arrays (`declare`) and parameter expansion `${var#...}`
various other forms.

It's generally best to avoid most such features, or use them sparingly, as the resulting scripts because progressively less portable as you use them ... and the syntactic machinations rapidly overwhelm the code.  At some point it's best to use Perl, Python, Ruby or some general purpose programming/scripting language for performing the general programming work and use shell for the purposes to which it was designed ... as glue around external commands, for marshaling data and variables into and out of those external commands/processes.